# Make a watermark a percentage of the original image size?

Tags: magento2, product-images, watermark

Magento 2 uses fixed pixel dimensions to specify the size of the product image watermark. This is a problem as the watermark could look very small or very big on the product image, depending on the product image size.

Instead, how could a module be developed to size the watermark image by a certain percentage of the original image size? This would ensure the watermark looks good on all images.